# Is there a way to use routing in two separate components in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use routing in two different components. First is the SIDEBAR component where links are there.... and a dynamic SHOWPANE component where other components will be rendered based on the routes provided by the sidebar.

Here is what I've tried...

```
//The App component
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="app-con">
          <Sidebar />
          <Showpane />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//The sidebar component
const sidebar = props => (
  <>
    <div className="sb-con">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Link to="/" className="navs">
            My Account
          </Link>
          <Link to="/history" className="navs">
            Account History
          </Link>
          <Link to="/settings" className="navs">
            Account Settings
          </Link>
          <Link to="/" className="navs">
            Log out
          </Link>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </>
);

//The showpane component
const showpane = props => (
  <>
    <div className="sp-con">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" component={Account} exact />
          <Route path="/history" component={Acchistory} />
          <Route path="/settings" component={Accset} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

I expect that after clicking Links in the sidebar component the showpane component must be rendered.

Comment: Is wrapping the two components with BrowserRouter a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

The `BrowserRouter` is your applications router, and therefore should sit at the top of your application's heirarchy.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div className="app-con">
            <Sidebar />
            <Showpane />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Your showpane will then look like:

```
const showpane = props => (
  <>
    <div className="sp-con">
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Account} exact />
        <Route path="/history" component={Acchistory} />
        <Route path="/settings" component={Accset} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

I would also recommend looking at the sidebar example [reacttraining's ReactRouter Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) since that is what you seem to be going for.

Comment: Thanks! I just wrapped the components to BrowserRouter.

Comment: Cool...remember that you don't need more than one Router instance in your component hierarchy. Keep just one instance at the top level.